# How do I set a ListViewSubItem BackColor in Windows Mobile?

Tags: winforms, windows-mobile, compact-framework, pinvoke

I'd like to change the BackgroundColor of a ListViewSubItem in a ListView in Windows Mobile. I'm using the Compact Framework ListView, whose ListViewItems only allow setting the BackColor on the entire row, which I don't want.

I have two questions:

1. Is this possible?
2. If this is possible, I *know* I have to P/Invoke to get this to work (because ListView.ListViewSubItem only offers a Text property), or send the right Windows message. What's the right function to call, or the right message to send?

Even just a pointer in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Christian Helle shows [how to custom draw CF ListViews here](http://christian-helle.blogspot.com/2009/10/listview-custom-drawing-in-netcf.html).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you need to draw the list view item yourself; use the default painting for the main item and do what you want for the subitem, [MSDN example here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446513.aspx#smartphoneuserinterface_topic9), or something like that.

Answer (score -1):

try to enable owner-draw true.. and set your own colour at drawingitem..
you wil get bounds.. draw your own colour

Comment: Technically the ListView in CE would be custom drawn, not owner drawn, and the CF ListView doesn't support either one.

Comment: yes.. you are exactly right, if you are using custom drawn then set owner-draw propertie true, and draw corresponding cell color there.
for more info see this controle
you can use this controle
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/uiframework/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=2315